# Image Upload Issues Same Image Different File Name Always Receive This Error

Tags: 8, media

We are currently working on fine tuning and updating the dev backend of our CMS we're rolling out for a new site.

I was familiarizing myself with the new system and uploaded some images in error.
I then deleted said images using module *Reports > Audit Files > Managed not Used*.
Once I removed the file another user tried to upload the same file with a different name and we keep getting this error.
We've removed the file from the Database and the  file server but still get the below error every time.

New to Drupal 8 and this forum... If you have solution or work around please let me know.

[image: Issue Uploading Image]

Answer (score 0):

You may have the [File Hash](https://www.drupal.org/project/filehash) module installed, and the *Optional duplicate file protection* feature enabled. That configuration would result in exactly the error message you're seeing, but obviously you may have custom code that does this instead.

If you are using File Hash, and don't want that functionality, you can either disable it at /admin/config/media/filehash, or uninstall the module entirely.